# Too much data in DomainAxis, another way of setTickUnit

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am creating chart like this:

```
            DefaultCategoryDataset cumulativeResultData = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
            DefaultCategoryDataset indexResultData = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
```

then in for loop im adding data to each Dataset using cumulativeResultData.addValue

```
            CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot();
            plot.setDomainAxis(new CategoryAxis("Days"));
            plot.setRangeAxis(new NumberAxis("Result"));
            plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);

            CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
            domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_45);


            LineAndShapeRenderer renderer2 = new LineAndShapeRenderer(true, false);
            LineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new LineAndShapeRenderer(true,  false);

            plot.setRenderer(renderer);
            plot.setDataset(cumulativeResultData);
            ValueAxis rangeAxis2 = new NumberAxis("Index price");
            rangeAxis2.setRange(minRange - 1, maxRange + 1);
            plot.setRangeAxis(1, rangeAxis2);
            plot.setRenderer(1, renderer2);
            plot.setDataset(1, indexResultData);
            plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(1, 1);

            JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(plot);
```

But what i get is not what i expected to get, please take a look in the picture bellow.
The domainAxis has to much data and it is blurred. Is any way to repair this? That only every for example 20th element shows on the domainAxis?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDvg7.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You should only use the [CategoryPlot](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CategoryPlot.html) class when your x-axis will show categorical data.  It looks like you have time series data, and for that you can use the [XYPlot](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html) class with a [DateAxis](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html) for the x-axis.  There is also the [TimeSeriesCollection](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeriesCollection.html) class that you can probably use for your dataset.